# Mixed effects model for partially repeated sampling?

Tags: mixed-model

I have a quick question about using mixed effects models for my dataset. Briefly, this is the data structure:

- I collected data from 8 study plots in 2011 and 18 study plots in 2012.
- 7 of the study plots used in 2011 were used again in 2012.
- I measured a response variable (Y) at each study plot in each year, and have four potential explanatory variables (V,W,X,Z) at each plot in each year.
- Y from 2011 is not correlated with Y from 2012 for the 7 sites where data were collected in both years.

My goal was to use multiple regression and stepwise AIC to identify which of the four explanatory variables best predicts the response variable Y. I used **lme** and **StepAIC** in R to run the analysis, using **lme(Y~V+W+X+Z, random = ~1|StudyPlot, method="ML")** as my starting model, with study plot included as a random effect to account for the fact that some plots were measured twice (thus, temporal pseudoreplication).

**But here's the question:** my advisor seems to recall that if there are only two time points in the repeated sampling, and not all study plots were sampled twice, it violates some assumption of the mixed model and thus I am not allowed to run this model with the 2011 data included and study plot included as a random effect.

I've looked many places to find information on this, but have not found information about this violation of assumptions (perhaps I'm not looking in the right places!!). I would very much appreciate any guidance or suggestions to literature I should consult. Thanks so much in advance--I've already learned so much from the experts in this forum by reading other researcher's posts!  :-)

Cheers,

James